# How to create a single codebase that works with both google apps script and browser?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, browserify

This is an issue that I can't get my head around of how to get it working the best way, i.e. when updates are made to the codebase BOTH google apps script Docs Add-on and browser version are updated. 
Let’s say I have a google apps script project that I want to publish, available both for Docs as an add-on and for the browser. This project however has a different implementation for the GAS version compared to the browser version.
Unfortunately, Browserify cannot be an option anymore as it appears to have broken backwards compatibility with Browserify in GAS. Any suggestion on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: By browser version do you mean an apps script web app?

Comment: I mean to not be dependent at all to goggle apps script, not even to onOpen() as an apps script web app would be (at least this is how I think it is), plain javascript project that could run on any browser.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to us a tool like Gulp Expose.

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-expose

For you browser build you would expose to `window`. For your apps script build you would expose to `this`.  Here is an example a Gulp task that builds a module out of Apps Script code. This is from the official Apps Script Oauth2 library found at https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var expose = require('gulp-expose');
var stripLine  = require('gulp-strip-line');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var del = require('del');
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var stylish = require('jshint-stylish');

gulp.task('dist', ['clean'], function() {
  gulp.src('src/*.gs')
      .pipe(gulpif(/OAuth2\.gs$/,
          stripLine('var _ =')))
      .pipe(concat('OAuth2.gs'))
      .pipe(expose('this', 'OAuth2'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
  gulp.src('node_modules/underscore/underscore.js')
      .pipe(rename('Underscore.gs'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
  del([
    'dist/*'
  ]);
});

gulp.task('lint', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/*.gs')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish));
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Just to clarify. Lets assume we have a basic docs add-on script such as the one here https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-templates/tree/master/docs-addon. How would I go about changing this script to develop a version that will both work on the browser and in the docs add-on? Clearly the logic that implements the interaction between sidebar and the actual google document needs to be abstracted but would the gulp-expose help with this scenario?

Comment: Just to add clarification Apps Script runs exclusively on google's infrastructure. It is a a server side language. You can create HTML interfaces, but all the Apps Script services run on the server side. So in light of that the only way you can write one code base that will run as an add-on and a stand alone webpage is to use the Execution API.